# How can I convert const std::vector<unsigned char> to char

Tags: c++

What would be the correct way to convert from unsigned char std::vector to char?

```
void SendSocket(const std::vector<BYTE> &buffer)
{
    int ret;
    const BYTE* bufferPtr = &buffer[0];
    ret = send(_socket, (const char*)bufferPtr, buffer.size(), 0);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It will be difficult to convert a vector (multiple elements) to a scalar item (one element), do you mean: How to get the address of the vector contents? But you code looks ok, do you have any problems with it?

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` are layout and alignment compatible, and the pointer cast is explicitly allowed. Your code is absolutely fine (and indeed it is allowed precisely to enable the use case you have).

Comment: Don't you mean `vector<unsigned char>` to `char*`?

Comment: Tip: `send` uses `const void *` for the array argument, so the code has an extra line and an extra cast, since anything except function pointers or pointers to members is implicitly cast to `void *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `BYTE` is a typedef for `char` (with or without `signed` or `unsigned`), then your code is fine, but slightly more verbose than necessary. The storage used by a `vector` is required to be a contiguous array, so taking the address of the first element gives you a pointer to that array. Any kind of `char` has the same layout and alignment as any other kind of `char`, so the pointer conversion is valid.

The argument to `send` is `const void*`, and (more or less) any pointer can be converted to that implicitly, so there's no need to cast:

```
ret = send(_socket, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), 0);
```

However, you should check (or otherwise ensure) that `buffer` isn't empty before using `[]`.